# Large file stock in remote server i cannot push i cannot delete it

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

i am not new to git but i must say i dont have advance user experience, i did add a file (mp4)without checking the size resulting to be really big, now for some weird reason git did not tell me right in that commit but in the next commit , i then deleted the file locally (manually remove it from the video folder and try to commit once again with the deleted file. i then jumped to try any possible solution of any situation that result on more commits!! now i am getting this messages and the file still somewhere in the story but i cannot find it, i cannot restort and i cannot lose my work.

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

THEN I PUSH AND :

```
Counting objects: 73, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.
Writing objects: 100% (73/73), 718.63 MiB | 897.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 73 (delta 57), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. 
remote: error: Trace: f010797db7ebbdf07ec4779755dc18f9
remote: error: See url for more information.
remote: error: File web/videos/modepalastried.mp4 is 719.64 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB to repo

[remote rejected] develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Myuser/repo.git'
```

I could try to delete all commits not yet pushed but i really did a lot of work i dont want to lost. I try to reset --soft but it did not work. i looked for the specific version and check if the file exist but says : file does not exist. Please Help

thank you <3

Answer (score 2):

The [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) is probably tailor-made for your needs - in your case, you might want to run it with a command like:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files modepalastried.mp4  my-repo.git
```

This removes all files named `modepalastried.mp4` that *aren't* in your latest commit.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: just for being the author of such a great tool +1. my favorite tool for such a task.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, ijust saw the BFG and clone -mirror but what i want is to use this in my current working copy not in a mirror and push a new one, i am pretty scared something goes wrong and i change the repository that is use for other developers

Answer (score 0):

### ***`How to remove big files from the repository`***

You can use `git filter-branch` or BFG. 
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

> #### ***`BFG Repo-Cleaner`***
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> *** Removing Crazy Big Files***
>   * Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

Comment: the file was commited  9 commits before , in between there is a few merges and i pulled also some changes so my working copy is the version we need in the remote repo. it is save to run the BFG in my current working copy ?   and another is, i already manually deleted the file but git tells me still there ! txs for the help

Comment: If you have a remote repository run BFG on your local clone. nothing can happen if you don't push, its pretty simple to use.

Comment: i tried to install BFG: first the system told me is not a know developer so i changed my settings to accept the file then double clcik but i get : The application “Jar Launcher” can’t be opened. so what should i do " sorry i am not really good in trhis type of things "

Comment: Do you have java installed?

Comment: i have a imac  OS X el capitan i suppost ihave i wil check anyways and come back to you !! txs

Comment: i updated it java from the oracle page now i double click on the file i dont get error but nothing opens ,  from right click openw with jar launcher i select also nothing happen, how can i check the BFG install ??

Comment: rxs ! i just did a workaround by doing a fresh installations and replace the files i wanted to keep from the older, not the best approach but all seems to work good txs a lot!